# Preserve method signature in simple decorator

Tags: typescript

Maybe someone can advise, I implemeted a simple decorator, that accepts method, adds some logic and returns back the method with the same signature.

```
type Method = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

 const useBusy = <T extends Method>(method: T): [boolean, T] => {
  const [isBusy, setIsBusy] = useState(false);
  const wrappedMethod = async (...args: any[]) => {
    setIsBusy(true);
    const result = await method.apply(this, args);
    setIsBusy(false)

    return result;
  }

  return [isBusy, wrappedMethod as T];
}

export default useBusy;
```

Is it possible to do the same but instead of array return object {IsBusy, method}? But I want to preserve name of passed method, for example if I do the following:

`const {isBusy, myMethod} = useBusy(myMethod)`
 I want typescript checks the response names, only isBusy and myMethod should be allowed.

Is it possible?

Comment: You would get a name clash. `myMethod` exists prior to definition, and you are defining it again. That being said, you can't access the name of the passed in parameter.. the best you can do is do a decomposition of an input object, and have a call something like `useBusy({myMethod})`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to the name of the passed object. What you can do is get an object as input, and output an extended version of that object as output.

```
const useBusy = <T extends { [k in keyof T]: Method }>(methodObj: T): T & { isBusy: boolean } => {
 ...
}
```

And then you can do:

```
const busy = useBusy({myMethod});
const isBusy = busy.isBusy;
const myBusyMethod = busy.myMethod;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=99&pln=1&pc=47#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATKBeKAKAdHghgE4DmAzgFxT4B2IA2gLoCUGAfFAAqFIC2AlqQgAeGiFYAoAMZJqpYFACuggEJKQGKEIAqUCAA9gEailJQA3lDoBrKH2pQrEEEgBmULQ0pxEqKAF9WLB54ZBQAeQAjACtKLSZKCwFVUhBKCKQkABsIGn8oADJ3NnNxKDKoQngFQntIqIhJYBx8UlI%20YmosMz8AGihgn3DovsTSZNSoYEIFaD8mAG5xP3FxFpBqSSgXBQ3gPhl%20kG9QrBYLZakZOSgItQ0lCHGuniOQ1DnF6Vl5W5SASTGd0wvxAOCSak%20V3kLzCiAghGOqAAcvhghoQTgXoiUIsgA)